# 'It is not difficult helping others' is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

I'm a student from south Korea. I'm learning English at school.
Today, I took an English test at school.
I've learned about

> 'It is ~ for ~ to ~'

sentence in school.
And I marked

> 'It is not difficult helping others'

sentence to 'X' (wrong).
But, my teacher changed the answer to 'O' (right). Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Can you explain what X and O mean?

Comment: I changed the formatting a little bit to make your question and context clearer (as we often request context). You can [edit] your post if you disagree or want to make more improvements. In English speaking regions, we use the check mark (✓) to mark something as correct. See [Details, Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/36187) and the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) for more tips and examples.

Comment: Could you indicate **why** you thought or think that "It is not difficult helping others" is wrong, please?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

To me, I'd prefer this:

> - It is not difficult to help others. (Similar to what you had learned)

Simply put, *difficult* here is an adjective that can be followed by a *to*-infinitive. In this case, you can only use the ing-verb if *difficult* is written in its noun form, *difficulty*.

> - There's no difficulty helping others.
> - There's no difficulty in helping others.

Use wisely!

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is equal to:

> **Helping others is not difficult**.

If you want to use the preposition
  **for**  you  may say:

> **It is not difficult for you or anybody to help others**

Comment: I could not figure out why not all gerund phrases don't work: It is not difficult helping others, does work. I invented a bunch of them and tried to substitute them and failed. Like this: acting silly is fun. It is fun acting silly. That one happens to work.